# Where to customise the mutter command line?

Tags: wayland

Recent versions of mutter have gained the ability to add virtual displays (`--virtual-display 1920x1080` for instance) - but I can't find where to customise the mutter command line.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Running 21.04 GNOME shell.

Comment: Oracle seems to be using it. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/mutter-1.html